# Generating sequence that uses the previous outcome for the current

Tags: ruby

I do not like to use `while` loops in Ruby. I was wondering how I can generate a "squared sequence" (e.g., squares the first input, then squares the outcome, etc.) in a more idiomatic Ruby way than this one:

```
value = 2
while value < 10000
    puts value = value**2
end

# => 4
#    16
#    256
#    65536
```

I have a suspicion that there is a way/method to do this, but I do not know which one. I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: You could also write, `value = 2; loop do; break if value >= 10_000; puts value = value**2; end`.

Answer (score 4):

Using `while` would be idiomatic in almost any language. `while` is basically *the* way to iterate, uh, *while* a condition is true. Hence the name - it's practically plain English.

You can postfix the `while` and save a couple of lines, but that's about it

```
puts value = value**2 while value < 10000
```

or use `until` if you want, but same difference

```
puts value = value**2 until value >= 10000
```

If you were dealing with a fixed or known number of iterations, you could do something like

```
4.times.inject(2) do |memo, _|
  puts memo = memo ** 2
  memo
end
```

but the whole point here is really that you don't know the number of iterations.

Answer (score -1):

I see nothing wrong in using the `while` word since your function logically is **doing smth while ...**
Wolfram Mathematica has [`NestWhile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestWhile.html), that can be implemented in Ruby like this:

```
def nest_while f, expr, test
  expr = f[expr] while test[expr]
end

nest_while ->i{ (i**2).tap &method(:puts) }, 2, ->i{ i<10000 }

4
16
256
65536
=> nil
```

Also you might be interested in implementing [`NestWhileList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestWhileList.html): using `yield` like at [SO: *Are there something like Python generators in Ruby?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2504494/322020).
.